# MongoDB: slow performance pipeline lookup compared to basic lookup

Tags: mongodb

I have two collection:

`matches`:

```
[{
    date: "2020-02-15T17:00:00Z",    
    players: [
      {_id: "5efd9485aba4e3d01942a2ce"}, 
      {_id: "5efd9485aba4e3d01942a2cf"}
    ]        
},
{...}]
```

and `players`:

```
 [{    
     _id: "5efd9485aba4e3d01942a2ce", 
     name: "Rafa Nadal"   
 },
 {    
     _id: "5efd9485aba4e3d01942a2ce", 
     name: "Roger Federer"   
 },
 {...}]
```

**I need to use lookup pipeline because I'm building a graphql resolver with recursive functions and I need nested lookup**. I've followed this example https://docs.mongodb.com/datalake/reference/pipeline/lookup-stage#nested-example

My problem is that with pipeline lookup I need 11 seconds but with basic lookup only 0.67 seconds. And my test database is very short! about 1300 players and  700 matches.

This is my pipeline lookup (11 seconds to resolve)

```
db.collection('matches').aggregate([{
   $lookup: {
      from: 'players',
      let: { ids: '$players' },            
      pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$ids' ] } } }],
      as: 'players'
   }
}]);
```

And this my basic lookup (0.67 seconds to resolve)

```
db.collection('matches').aggregate([{
   $lookup: {
     from: "players",
     localField: "players",
     foreignField: "_id",
     as: "players"
   }
}]);
```

Why so much difference? In what way can I do faster pipeline lookup?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that when you do a `lookup` using `pipeline` with a match stage, then the index would be used only for the fields that are matched with `$eq operator` and for the rest index will not be used.

And the example you specified with pipeline will work like this ( *again index will not be used here as it is not* `$eq` )

```
db.matches.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "players",
      let: {
        ids: {
          $map: {
            input: "$players",
            in: "$$this._id"
          }
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$_id",
                "$$ids"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "players"
    }
  }
])
```

As players is an array of object so it need to be mapped to array of ids first

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_sQRQbcLDvL)

Comment: I deleted the previous answer, as I thought that $eq worked with arrays, but the idea is this only that index in the pipeline only works with the $eq operator

Comment: you can read it here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/lvRsC-RRHpc

Comment: Then, would be great something like: `pipeline: [{ '$match': { '$expr': { $or: [{ '$eq': ['$_id', '$$ids.0'] },{ '$eq': ['$_id', '$$ids.1'] }] } } } ]`

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32549 , this is the jira toicket I found for the same issue

Comment: I don't know whether using `$or` will help or not (we can try running it), but one more solution that we can use is that first, we unwind the player's ids and the use $eq operator

example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/FGAY-jFBG1_

Comment: again we can check whether it use any index or not with the `explain()` method

Comment: @kurtko did that help ?

Answer (score 0):

As @namar sood comments there are several tickets that refer to this issue:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-37470

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32549

Meanwhile a solution could be (also works nested):

```
db.collection('matches').aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$players' },
  {
   $lookup: {
      from: 'players',
      let: { id: '$players' },            
      pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$id' ] } } }],
      as: 'players'
  },
  { $unwind: '$players' },
  {
    $group: {
       "_id": "$_id",        
       "data": { "$first": "$$ROOT" },
       "players": {$push: "$players"}        
    }
  },
  { $addFields: {"data.players": "$players"} },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" }}
]);
```