# How to find by referenced Object's property in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two models, made using Mongoose Schema.

```
Book {
    title: String,
    chapters: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'chapter'
    }],
}

Chapter {
    title: String,
    status: String,
    book: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'book'
    },
}
```

I want to find `Books` that have a chapter with `"status":"unfinished"`. What is the most efficient way to achieve this? Since the Book model stores ObjectIds, how can I make the find query so that the filtered results will be fetched directly from the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most optimal way would be to **denormalize** your schema, as a `book` will have a `limited amount of chapters` and a chapter can belong to `at most one book`, we can store the schema like this

```
Book {
    title: String,
    chapters: [{
         title: String,
         status: String,
    }],
}
```

with this schema, we can then create an index on '`chapters.status`' and simply get the answer in a single query without the need of `$lookup`.

```
db.books.find({'chapters.status': 'unfinished'});
```

---

But in any case, you still need to go with the above schema, we always have an option for `$lookup`

```
db.book.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$chapters",
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "chapter",
      localField: "chapters",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "chapter",
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "chapter.status": "unfinished",
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      title: { $first: "$title" },
    },
  },
]);
```

You can always adjust the above query to your needs.

[Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hrfgSGr9wOA)

Comment: hey, did this answer your query?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/index.html),

- [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) with pipeline, join Chapter collection
- [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) 2 conditions first match chapter _id in chaptersIds, second status is equal to `unfinished`
- `$match` to match chapters not equal to empty array
- [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) to show or hide required fields

```
db.Book.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "Chapter",
      as: "chapters_list",
      let: { chapterIds: "$chapters" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $in: ["$_id", "$$chapterIds"] },
                { $eq: ["$status", "unfinished"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $match: { chapters_list: { $ne: [] } }
  },
  // if you want chapters_list array then remove $project this part
  {
    $project: { chapters: 1, title: 1 }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jv_RWDgSE-X)

Comment: in `$lookup`, `$match` in the pipeline only uses index with $eq

Comment: i am not getting you are you asking? you can use pipeline as normal as we are using outside lookup.

Comment: I am saying that only a `$eq` can use index inside the pipeline of `$lookup`

Comment: okay, you know is there any reference documentation for that? how you know?

Comment: you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952013/mongodb-slow-perfomance-pipeline-lookup-compared-to-basic-lookup/62952478#62952478

Comment: nice i did't know about this, thanks for the information.