# is this the right way to join two collections and combine results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to join two collections and get fields from both the collections. Collections have very basic structure and this is how they look like:

```
"products": [
    {
      "_id": 0,
      "name": "product 0",
      "desc": "some product",
      "sales_reps": [
        {
          "sales_rep_id": 0,
          "is_doing_good": true
        },
        {
          "sales_rep_id": 1,
          "is_doing_good": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

  "sales_rep_master": [
    {
      "_id": 0,
      "name": "sales rep 0"
    },
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "sales rep 1"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "sales rep 2"
    }
  ]
```

I am trying to join them on `products.sales_reps.sales_rep_id = sales_rep_master._id`. This is how my query looks like:

```
[
  {
    "$match": { <--Filter on product._id
      "_id": 0 
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": { <-- Expand sales reps array
      "path": "$sales_reps" 
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": { <-- join with sales rep master and filter our where is_doing_well is false
      "from": "sales_rep_master",
      "let": {
        "sr_id": "$sales_reps.sales_rep_id",
        "is_doing_well": "$sales_reps.is_doing_good"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$expr": {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$_id",
                    "$$sr_id"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "$expr": {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$$is_doing_well",
                    true
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "doing_good": "$$is_doing_well"
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "sales_reps"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": { <<- expand newly created sales reps array
      "path": "$sales_reps"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": { <-- Group product and sales reps
      "_id": "$_id",
      "product": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      },
      "sales_reps": {
        "$push": "$sales_reps"
      }
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$set": { <-- add sales_reps inside product
      "product.sales_reps": "$sales_reps"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": { <-- replace root
      "newRoot": "$product"
    }
  }
]
```

This query is working fine and I am getting expected output but I feel like I am doing something wrong here as this seems to be doing too much just to get fields from two collections. There are more stages after that which I have excluded.

Here is the demo: https://mongoplayground.net/p/_Tz3fm4a-J8

Am I doing something wrong here or this is how it is supposed to be?

Comment: I just need to know, `{"$expr":{"$eq":["$$is_doing_well",true]}}` why are you checking this inside pipeline? Pipeline is to use joining table stages. `is_doing_well` is in your `product` collection. So if you need to check `is_doing_well:true`, you can do it before lookup. DOes https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jq7ohYeqwub help you, if its, i can brief my answer

Comment: Hi @varman for the knowledge, `$in` inside lookup pipeline will not use index if its provided, look this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952013/mongodb-slow-performance-pipeline-lookup-compared-to-basic-lookup) and follow the links and tickets.

Comment: @turivishal I just went through https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32549 ticket. `$unwind` costs more terrible performance when we have thousands of records as we know.

Comment: @turivishal And he indicated that he needs to match two variables.(may be his scenario is wrong, and I questioned it). I can be done with regular lookup and needs more stages

Comment: @varman yup you are right for $unwind, look at the question, in first pipeline he is searching using `_id` it will return only one document, and second i think its not good approach to store thousands of array elements, if array field contains limited data then, its good deal to unwind only for one document's array, your approach is really good but it depends on OP's original data. i will check `explain` stat for both approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your query,

- `$match` you both conditions, to reduce unmatched documents
- `$unwind` deconstruct `sales_reps` array
- `$match` `sales_reps.is_doing_good` condition to reduce unmatched document
- `$lookup` to join collection
- `$unwind` deconstruct `sales_reps`
- `$addFields` to add field `doing_good`
- `$group` by id and reconstruct `sales_reps` array

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: 0,
      "sales_reps.is_doing_good": true
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$sales_reps" },
  { $match: { "sales_reps.is_doing_good": true } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "sales_rep_master",
      localField: "sales_reps.sales_rep_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "sales_reps"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$sales_reps" },
  { $addFields: { "sales_reps.doing_good": true } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      desc: { $first: "$desc" },
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      sales_reps: { $push: "$sales_reps" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tZz9jGtKt61)

---

Another possible way, reduce `$addFields` pipeline from above example,

- `$mergeObjects` to merge field in side `$push`

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      desc: { $first: "$desc" },
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      sales_reps: {
        $push: {
          $mergeObjects: [{ doing_good: true }, "$sales_reps"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JZJpIBwVDxy)

---

> For the reference follow [aggregation-pipeline-optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/), compare query's response stats using [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The part that can be simplified, is the `$lookup` by using `localField` and `foreignField`

Then I tied a different approach with a `$project` instead of the `$set` and `$replaceRoot`

---

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zTfiTQZ0WZI)

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$sales_reps"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "sales_rep_master",
      "localField": "sales_reps.sales_rep_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "sales_rep_master"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$sales_rep_master"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "desc": 1,
      "name": 1,
      "sales_rep_master": 1,
      "sales_reps": {
        "_id": "$sales_rep_master._id",
        "name": "$sales_rep_master.name",
        "doing_good": "$sales_reps.is_doing_good",
        
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "desc": {
        "$first": "$desc"
      },
      "name": {
        "$first": "$name"
      },
      "sales_reps": {
        "$addToSet": "$sales_reps"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few thing I consider. You don't need to use `$expr` for each condition. If you going to use `$in` to compare, then you don't need to `$unwind`. `$unwind` cost always when we increase data. Ref [JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-32549). But considering data size, you can use `$in` or `$unwind`.

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      sales_reps: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$sales_reps",
          cond: {
            $eq: [ "$$this.is_doing_good", true]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "sales_rep_master",
      "let": { "sr_id": "$sales_reps.sales_rep_id" },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                { "$in": [ "$_id","$$sr_id"] },
                // { other condition }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "doing_good": true
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "sales_reps"
    }
  }
])
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ifYcYQxnlkJ)

Comment: this falls apart if I add a text field as you have kind of hardcoded doing_good to `true`. https://mongoplayground.net/p/AXwJX4O1XYv